# CollapsingToolbarLayout define animation start

Tags: android, android-design-library

How could I change the starting of animation in CollapsingToolbarLayout? I figured out that animation is controlled by the `app:contentScrim` attribute.
But the "alpha" animation is starting too soon. Could I change the animation attributes somehow?  I guess by the height so about "200dp".

For example, if I would define `<CollapsingToolbarLayout... layout_height="150dp" >` I don't even see the image because it's already hidden by the animation at the beginning. Here is my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/paralax_tabs_collapse_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="@color/my_action_bar_color"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="10dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/paralax_tabs_header_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/paralax_tabs_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleMarginTop="13dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/paralax_tabs_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/app_tab_backgorund"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />
</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Im afraid the solution is not easy.

I've had to create my own CollapsingToolbarLayout changing the original.

Original:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/6ba61c5/design/src/android/support/design/widget

In my case I changed the getScrimTriggerOffset method

From:

```
final int getScrimTriggerOffset() {
    return 2 * ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight(this);
}
```

to:

```
final int getScrimTriggerOffset() {
    return 3 * ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight(this);
}
```

This method is used in line 677 of CollapsingToolbarLayout to determine if show or hide the content scrim.

```
// Show or hide the scrims if needed
if (mContentScrim != null || mStatusBarScrim != null) {
     if (getHeight() + verticalOffset < getScrimTriggerOffset() + insetTop) {
         showScrim();
     } else {
         hideScrim();
     }
}
```

I tried to extend CollapsingToolbarLayout and override this method but its declared as final.

I'm sorry for the late reply, hope it works

Answer (score 0):

1. Create you own CollapsingToolbarLayout.
2. Override next functions: [setScrimsShown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#setScrimsShown%28boolean%29)(show/hide content scrim),onAttachedToWindow and onDetachedFromWindow.
3. In onAttachedToWindow create [AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener.html) and add to the parent.In onDetachedFromWindow remove listener.(**works only if parent is AppBarLayout**).
4. In setScrimsShown set the rules to start animation.

Example:

```
public class MyCollapsingLayout extends CollapsingToolbarLayout {
    private int mCurrentVOffset = 0;
    private AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener mListener = null;

    ...

    @Override
    public void setScrimsShown(boolean shown) {
        boolean show = /*your code */

        super.setScrimsShown(show);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        final ViewParent parent = getParent();

        if (parent instanceof AppBarLayout) {
            mListener = new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                    mCurrentVOffset = verticalOffset;
                }
            };
            ((AppBarLayout) parent).addOnOffsetChangedListener(mListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        final ViewParent parent = getParent();
        if (mListener != null && parent instanceof AppBarLayout) {
            ((AppBarLayout) parent).removeOnOffsetChangedListener(mListener);
        }

        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#attr_android.support.design:scrimVisibleHeightTrigger) you need to call the method on CollapsingToolbarLayout

```
setScrimVisibleHeightTrigger(int)
```

> **android.support.design:scrimVisibleHeightTrigger**
>
> Specifies the amount of visible height in pixels used to define when
>   to trigger a scrim visibility change.

For support design library version: `26.1.0`